# regex question - to match a string when not equal to

Tags: regular-expression

My Regex :

```
^[0-9]{9}_(010020)(004)-[0-9,a-z,A-Z]+__[0-9]{8}_[0-9]{4}
```

To Match following string:

```
010020004_010020004-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx_20180105_1606
```

The above works okay...but if I want to match a string when it is not equal to (004) bolded. I tried negative lookahead (?!004) it doesn't match the string

```
^[0-9]{9}_(010020)**(?!004)**-[0-9,a-z,A-Z]+__[0-9]{8}_[0-9]{4}

010020004_010020005-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx_20180105_1606
```

Am I missing something

Comment: What regular expression engine are you matching with? Is it `grep` or something else? If it's in some other programming language, then it may be off-topic here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your pattern and answer from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1971738/regex-for-all-strings-not-containing-a-string: the following pattern work in my editor:
`^[0-9]{9}_(010020).*(?<!004)-[0-9,a-z,A-Z]+_[0-9]{8}_[0-9]{4}`

I think there is an extra underscore in your pattern after the '+' sign.
And we have to match the last 3 character before checking they are not "004").

Depending on the exact formatting you might want to ensure we are only matching 3 digits: `^[0-9]{9}_(010020)([0-9]*(?<!004)){3}-[0-9,a-z,A-Z]+_[0-9]{8}_[0-9]{4}`